# FAIL - Tried to use command /upload via a GET request but POST is required Deploy Geoserver.war

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy geoserver.war on tomcat7 but a message error is shown:

> FAIL - Tried to use command /upload via a GET request but POST is required

What should I do?

Comment: you need to give use more of a clue as to what you are trying to do. Usually you just copy the war file to the webapps folder.

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs when your *.war* is bigger than the value in config file of the tomcat manager.
You need to set the config in web.xml from the tomcat manager.
The file will normally be in `%tomcat installation%\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml`

Look for:

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 50MB max -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

and change the values.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Samuel's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136579), I searched for a good while until I found it in:

```
/usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

A bit different path, might help.